# How to implement pagination in backward way eg. first - 20 - 19 - 18 - ... - 3 - 2 - 1 - last

Tags: pagination, seo, customization

How can I implement pagination in backward style, like shown in the title.

(newest) first - 20 - 19 - 18 - ... - 3 - 2 - 1 - last (oldest)

I have search plugin, there are not yet plugin for this.
Because I want static pagination result, for SEO, I hope I'm not wrong with this opinion.

Thank You.

**EDIT**

I try to explain with sample.

eg.: every page limit by 3 posts and have total 15 posts (total 5 pages).
The position in Blog Home Default is page 5 (because the latest pages are 5).
So the blog home display like this:

```
(date) - Title
**15** Jan 2011 - A dummy title
**14** Jan 2011 - A dummy title
**13** Jan 2011 - A dummy title
pagination display: (5) - 4 - 3 - 2 - 1
```

And if I click page 4, content entry not display correctly, it display like this:

```
(date) - Title
**06** Jan 2011 - A dummy title
**05** Jan 2011 - A dummy title
**04** Jan 2011 - A dummy title
pagination display: 5 - (4) - 3 - 2 - 1
```

Instead of that, page 4 should be like this:

```
**12** Jan 2011 - A dummy title
**11** Jan 2011 - A dummy title
**10** Jan 2011 - A dummy title
pagination display: 5 - (4) - 3 - 2 - 1
```

> notes: I also put sample with **date**, to
>   make it clear sample.

How can this will happen without touching the core Wordpress?
Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `wp_paginate_links()`, pass it the `'type' => 'array'` parameter in the argument array, and then `array_reverse()` the output.

But: if you're doing this for SEO purposes, *don't bother*. Your canonical URL should be your *single-post view*, not an archive index; so the index archive page numbers should have minimal SEO impact, no matter what order the page numbering.

**EDIT**

`wp_paginate_links()` [Codex ref](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links)

**EDIT 2**

If you want to reverse the order of the posts themselves, you'll either need to use a custom query, or modify the default Loop query, likely by changing the `$order` from `DESC` to `ASC`.

**EDIT 3**

If you *just* want to reverse the order of the *posts themselves*, then just change `$order` from `DESC` to `ASC`, and don't do an `array_reverse()` on the `wp_paginate_links()` call.

Comment: Thank you! It works, but this only for the pagination display, the list loop content at page is still the same as before, I want the result also in backward, but NOT the order/sort of posts, it should be like normal, the newest is the first display (with LAST pagination number), and the latest is the oldest posts (with page ONE pagination number). Can this will happen without touching the core Wordpress?

Comment: I mean if I go to page 1, the posts results is not the LATEST post, page 1 should be the latest posts. And the End of page should be the newest posts. It seems this will be so difficult to implement.

Comment: See answer update.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but changing the $order from DESC to ASC will not display the newest in first display. I just want a normal display newest in the first display (define as last page number), the oldest latest display (define as page ONE). So I must keep `$order` with `DESC`.

Comment: @Jawaad then you need to clarify what *exactly* you're after, because I no longer understand.

Comment: Please if you don't mind, see question update. Thank You.

Comment: @Jawaad I will take a look shortly; thanks for the clarification.